# Java streams average

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to create two methods using streams. A method that returns an average score of each task.

```
    public Map<String, Double> averageScoresPerTask(Stream<CourseResult> results) {}
```

and a method that returns a task with the highest average score.

```
    public String easiestTask(Stream<CourseResult> results) {}
```

I can only modify those 2 methods.

Here is CourseResult class

```
public class CourseResult {
    private final Person person;
    private final Map<String, Integer> taskResults;

    public CourseResult(final Person person, final Map<String, Integer> taskResults) {
        this.person = person;
        this.taskResults = taskResults;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getTaskResults() {
        return taskResults;
    }
}
```

And methods that create CourseResult objects.

```
private final String[] programTasks = {"Lab 1. Figures", "Lab 2. War and Peace", "Lab 3. File Tree"};
private final String[] practicalHistoryTasks = {"Shieldwalling", "Phalanxing", "Wedging", "Tercioing"};

private Stream<CourseResult> programmingResults(final Random random) {
    int n = random.nextInt(names.length);
    int l = random.nextInt(lastNames.length);

    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            .limit(3)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Person(
                    names[(n + i) % names.length],
                    lastNames[(l + i) % lastNames.length],
                    18 + random.nextInt(20)))
            .map(p -> new CourseResult(p, Arrays.stream(programTasks).collect(toMap(
                    task -> task,
                    task -> random.nextInt(51) + 50))));
}

private Stream<CourseResult> historyResults(final Random random) {
    int n = random.nextInt(names.length);
    int l = random.nextInt(lastNames.length);
    AtomicInteger t = new AtomicInteger(practicalHistoryTasks.length);

    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            .limit(3)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Person(
                    names[(n + i) % names.length],
                    lastNames[(l + i) % lastNames.length],
                    18 + random.nextInt(20)))
            .map(p -> new CourseResult(p,
                    IntStream.iterate(t.getAndIncrement(), i -> t.getAndIncrement())
                            .map(i -> i % practicalHistoryTasks.length)
                            .mapToObj(i -> practicalHistoryTasks[i])
                            .limit(3)
                            .collect(toMap(
                                    task -> task,
                                    task -> random.nextInt(51) + 50))));
}
```

Based on these methods I can calculate an average of each task by dividing sum of scores of this task by 3, because there are only 3 Persons tho I can make it so it divides by a number equal to number of CourseResult objects in a stream if these methods get their .limit(3) changed.
I don't know how to access keys of taskResults Map. I think I need them to then return a map of unique keys. A value for each unique key should be an average of values from taskResults map assigend to those keys.

Comment: `access keys of taskResults Map and group by the keys where values are average of values for the given key` - this sentence is confusing. What should be the final result (both in plain words and as an object in Java) ?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko The final result should be that I get tests and their average scores calculated from scores of different people (different CourseResults). It should be a Map<String, Double> where String is test and Double is average score of this test.
For easiestTask method the returned result should be just the test with highest average.
I edited for hopefully more clarity.

Comment: I think the signature of the method that is responsible for calculating the easiest task is incorrect. You're generating a stream `Stream<CourseResult>` using random values, this data doesn't exist somewhere. Hence, you can pass this stream only a one of these methods because a stream can be executed only once (once it hit the terminal operation it's being closed, and you can't use it anymore).

Comment: Therefore, to fix this, you can make `easiestTask()` expect a map produced by the `programmingResults()` as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: map each `CourseResult` to `taskResults`, flatmap to get all entries of each `taskResults` map form all `CourseResult`s, group by map keys (task names) and collect averaging the values for same keys:

```
public Map<String, Double> averageScoresPerTask(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    return results.map(CourseResult::getTaskResults)
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.averagingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));
}
```

You can use the same approach for your second question to calculate the average for each task and finaly stream over the entries of the resulting map to find the task with the highest average.

```
public String easiestTask(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    return results.map(CourseResult::getTaskResults)
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.averagingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElse("No easy task found");
}
```

To avoid code duplication you can call the first method within the second:

```
public String easiestTask(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    return averageScoresPerTask(results).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElse("No easy task found");
}
```

**EDIT**

To customize the calculation of the average regardless how many items your maps contain, don't use the inbuilt operations like `Collectors.averagingInt` or `Collectors.averagingDouble`. Instead wrap your collector in `collectingAndThen` and sum the scores using `Collectors.summingInt` and finally after collecting divide using a divisor according if the task name starts with `Lab` or not:

```
public Map<String, Double> averageScoresPerTask(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    return results.map(CourseResult::getTaskResults)
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)),
                    map -> map.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    e -> e.getKey().startsWith("Lab") ? e.getValue() / 3. : e.getValue() / 4.))
                    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, you and Alexander really helped me today you Java Stream monsters :D

Comment: Hey it is actually workin well BUT I can't use Collectos.averagingInt because I have to actually always divide the sum of, for example "Phalanxing" scores, by 3 not just get an average which is sometimes getting a sum of entries with "Phalanxing" key and dividing it by 2 because 2 persons attempted it but it should divide by 3 because if 3rd person doesn't have a score for "Phalanxing" it just means he scored 0.
Yes if you remember my earlier topic the CourseResult generating method overcomplicates things.

Comment: @fireballun You are welcome. If Alexander´s answer solves your problem I will either update my answer with alternative aproach, so feature users with similar tasks have more choise, or delete it.

Comment: Hey, Alexander's approach would actually solve my problem if not for that weird requirement of practically always dividing by number of CourseResults objects or by just by 3 considering historyResults has .limit(3). I would not delete Alexander's approach tho because normally it would be enough.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Will update my answer shortly when I get home.

Comment: Awesom! You really are a goat :D

Answer (score 1):

To create a *map* containing an *average score* for each *task*, you need to flatten the map `taskResults` of every `CourseResult` result object in the stream and group the data by *key* (i.e. by task name).

For that you can use *collector* `groupingBy()`, as its *downstream collector* that would be responsible for calculation the *average* from the score-values mapped to the same *task* you can use `averagingDouble()`.

That's how it might look like:

```
public Map<String, Double> averageScoresPerTask(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    
    return results
        .map(CourseResult::getTaskResults)       // Stream<Map<String, Integer>> - stream of maps
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()) // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> - stream of entries
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.averagingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)
        ));
}
```

To find the easiest task, you can use this map instead of passing the stream as an argument because the logic of this method requires applying the same operations. It would make sense in the real life scenario when you're retrieving the data that is stored somewhere (*it would be better to avoid double-processing it*) and more over in your case you can't generate a stream from the source twice and pass into these two methods because in your case stream data is random. Passing the same stream into both method is not an option because you can execute a stream pipeline only **once**, when it hits the *terminal operation* - it's done, you can't use it anymore, hence you can't pass the same stream with random data in these two methods.

```
public String easiestTask(Map<String, Double>  averageByTask) {
    
    return averageByTask.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // produces result of type Optianal<Map.Entry<String, Double>>
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)            // transforming into Optianal<String>
        .orElse("no data");                // or orElseThrow() if data is always expected to be present depending on your needs
}
```